# TF.exe doesn't prompt for checkin confirmation when executed directly, without using the operating system shell to start the process

Tags: vb.net, tfs, tf-cli

I'm using `TF.exe` command-line for some simple TFS commands such as getting the latest version of the files (`tf.exe vc get`), checking out some files (`tf.exe vc checkout`) and then checking them in at the end of use (`tf.exe vc checkin`).

After some tests I've noticed that when I run the checkin command through Windows Command Prompt (`cmd.exe`), the prompt window is displayed asking for confirmation before the check-in command is done:

```console
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
  \Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer>
      tf.exe vc checkin "C:\TfsTestProject\test.txt" /comment:"Checked via command-line."
```

[image: Window displayed asking for checkin confirmation]

For my project that was a good thing, displaying the prompt window for check-in confirmation.

However, when I started the TF command through code I found a problem: I have to start the `TF.exe` process redirecting the standard output, so I can display what's happening when the command is executed, and for that I have to set `process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False`. But when I do that, the prompt window is no longer displayed, as if I was using the `/noprompt` parameter (and I'm not using it).

So, when I use the code below the prompt window is stil displayed, as in the picture, but I cannot receive the standard output stream feedback:

```vbnet
Dim p = New Process()
' I removed the full path for clarity, but that's:
' "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\TF.exe"
p.StartInfo.FileName = "TF.exe"
p.StartInfo.Arguments = $"vc checkin ""{testFilePath}"" /comment:""Checked via code."""
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True

p.Start()
p.WaitForExit()
```

But, when I use this other code, the one that I need, the prompt window for check-in confirmation is no longer displayed, even though I'm not using `/noprompt` parameter:

```vbnet
Dim p = New Process()
' I removed the full path for clarity, but that's:
' "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\TF.exe"
p.StartInfo.FileName = "TF.exe"
p.StartInfo.Arguments = $"vc checkin ""{testFilePath}"" /comment:""Checked via code."""
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False   ' <- That's the problem, apparently.
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True

p.EnableRaisingEvents = True
AddHandler p.OutputDataReceived, Sub(s, e) Console.WriteLine(e.Data)

p.Start()
p.BeginOutputReadLine()
p.WaitForExit()
```

I couldn't find any information about that behaviour, maybe it's just a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shame on me, I've done some research before posting the question and found nothing, but, just after posting it I found this:

[c# - How can I capture tf.exe stderr without stopping its dialog prompts? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13837385/8133067)

This problem is old, since that question is from 10 years ago, facing the same "bug". Apparently there is an undocumented parameter `/prompt` that makes the prompt window to be displayed even though the TF command is not executed through shell.

So this code (with undocumented `/prompt` parameter) worked:

```vbnet
Dim p = New Process()
' I removed the full path for clarity, but that's:
' "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\TF.exe"
p.StartInfo.FileName = "TF.exe"
' With undocumented /prompt parameter the prompt window is
' displayed even when the command is not executed through shell.
p.StartInfo.Arguments = $"vc checkin ""{testFilePath}"" /prompt /comment:""Checked via code."""
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True

p.EnableRaisingEvents = True
AddHandler p.OutputDataReceived, Sub(s, e) Console.WriteLine(e.Data)

p.Start()
p.BeginOutputReadLine()
p.WaitForExit()
```

And after that question and answer from long time ago I've tested a little more and found that I was wrong, the problem is not about not starting the command from shell, the problem really happens when the streams (output or error) are redirected. When you just set `UseShellExecute = False`, without redirecting, the prompt window is still displayed.

Comment: you stole my answer. I was about to say `/prompt`

Comment: Sorry about that! And thanks, anyway!

Comment: Hi @Pedro, thanks for sharing your answer. You could [mark your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) so that people with the same questions can benefit.

Comment: Hi @SukiJi-MSFT, yeah, I'm gonna do that, I was just waiting some time before doing it to give others answers a chance.